# использование setattr для добавления атрибутов в JSON файл

Tags: python, json

Суть вопроса заключается в том,что у нас есть Json файл ,мы не знаем как и чем он заполнен. Мне нужно как-то пройтись по уникальным именам в Json файле,и если это имя есть,то нужно пройтись по атрибутам,этого имени,проверить,есть ли нужный мне атрибут,если есть,то ничего не делать,если нет  - добавить его,атрибуты записаны будут в виде ключ:значение.....А если уникально имени не существует,то вывести ошибку...не знаю как организовать алгоритм проверки на уникальное имя и существование атрибутов,предполагаю,что добавлять можно через setattr.буду признателен,если кто-то сможет помочь

Comment: [Документация по dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict), [документация по json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html). Какие именно затруднения у вас возникают при решении вашей задачи после чтения документации?

Comment: проблема в том,что я не знаю ,как организовать цикл поиска уникального имени,а потом в нём наличия нужных мне полей....мой цикл ищет имя,но потом проходит не по его полям,а по буквам названия уникального имени

Comment: json это не xml